# SHA-256 hash return different results

Tags: java

We need to hash string using SHA-256.

This is the code I have:

```
public String getSHA256HashedString(String clearString) {
    String _LOC = "[SB_UtilityBean: getSHA256HashedString]";

    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(clearString.getBytes());

        String _encrypted = bytesToHex(md.digest());
        System.out.println(_LOC + "1.0 " + " Result 1: " + _encrypted);
        System.out.println(_LOC + "1.0 " + " Result 2: " + bytesToHex(md.digest()));

        return _encrypted;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    String _LOC = "[SB_UtilityBean: bytesToHex]";

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte byt : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((byt & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

    return result.toString();
}
```

If `bytesToHex(md.digest())` is assigned to a variable `_encrypted` and do a print line of `_encrypted`, I get Result 1:

> `9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08`

If I do a print line of `bytesToHex(md.digest())`, I get Result 2:

> `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest()) says (emphasis mine):

> `public byte[] digest()`
>
> Completes the hash computation by performing final operations such as padding. **The digest is reset after this call is made.**

Your second call to `digest()` is therefore getting the hash of no bytes, not of your input string. You must either feed the string in again, or use the stored result.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I see. So Result 1 is the correct hashed?

Comment: @bittersour Yes. The second hash (`e3b…855`) is the SHA256 sum of an empty buffer.